# Fixing simple java recursion code

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static boolean work(String str, char ch)
```

Use recursion to find out if str contains at least one occurrence of ch.
Return true if it does and false if not.
Example

> work("whynot", 'n') returns true
>       work("please", 'z') returns false

```
public static boolean work(String str, char ch){
    //base case 
    if (str == null || str.equals("")){
        return false; 
    }

    //recursive case
    if (ch == str.charAt(0)){
        return true; 
    }else {
        work(str.substring(1), ch); 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

My code will correctly return "true" when ch is the first character of str, but return an incorrect answer of "false" when ch is in any other part of the str.

Please explain why... I was thinking it was because my last "return false;" statement overrode the "true" from the recursive case if, but when I get rid of the last "return false;" my compiler will complain that I'm missing a return value.

Comment: Why are you calling         contains(str.substring(1), ch);  instead of work?

Comment: You keep changing the name of you function (should be "work", but was "contains", now it's "work", but you're calling "contains" inside...) clean that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not returning the result of the recursive call.

Try this:

```
public static boolean work(String str, char ch){
    //base case 
    if (str == null || str.equals("")){
        return false; 
    }

    //recursive case
    if (ch == str.charAt(0)){
        return true; 
    }else {
        return work(str.substring(1), ch); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. However, is it true that my last return false statement can override the true from the if statement above?

Comment: Not now that the code is fixed. There's no further processing after a return code (set exception handling aside), and if both branches of an if statement end in a return, that's as far as it goes. (P.S. - You like the answer? accept it! :-)

Comment: Yes I will, but the site won't let me until 10 mins has passed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Think about it for a second. If the function "work" returns true, then if you do not return this what will happen? The else statement will end and it will return false - even if the inner call returned true.

Comment: This looks like an exercise problem to try understand exactly this kind of behavior :)

Comment: @Bluejay It does not override anything. The inner function call returns true... and then the outer function call completely ignores that and returns false. Exactly the same as if you were calling some function non-recursively (imagine if `work(str.substring(1), ch);` was replaced by `str.substring(1).contains(ch)`)